# Should or should not catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException while updating an item (EF Core)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a table that stores the user notification settings. Essentially, if a new user is created, there will be no data for him until this command is called. Subsequent calls to this command should update the existing record.

The question is how do I do it correctly? Nick Chapsas recently published a video about [GPT-4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4sDzidCudQ). If you look at the output he got for the update operation, there is a try/catch block that catches `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

```cs
public sealed class UpsertUserNotificationSettingsCommand : IRequest
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid EventTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool NotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
    public Guid? SoundId { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UpsertUserNotificationSettingsCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<UpsertUserNotificationSettingsCommand>
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public UpsertUserNotificationSettingsCommandHandler(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task Handle(UpsertUserNotificationSettingsCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var userNotificationSettings = await _context.UserNotificationSettings.FindAsync(new object[] { request.UserId, request.EventTypeId }, cancellationToken);
        
        if (userNotificationSettings == null)
        {
            // It does not exist, so insert it.
            var entity = new UserNotificationSettings
            {
                UserId = request.UserId,
                EventTypeId = request.EventTypeId,
                NotificationsEnabled = request.NotificationsEnabled,
                SoundId = request.SoundId
            };
        
            _context.UserNotificationSettings.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            // It exists, so update it.
            // It automatically does `_context.Entry(userNotificationSettings).State = EntityState.Modified;`
            userNotificationSettings.NotificationsEnabled = request.NotificationsEnabled;
            userNotificationSettings.SoundId = request.SoundId;
        }

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said, that was a video on ChatGPT, not good EF practices. This is a bad one - it ignores the error losing your changes. There's no magic bullet - do you ignore the error and store your changes over the existing changes? Discard your changes the way this code does? Ask the user? MediatR certainly has nothing to do with this concurrency question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I removed MediatR from the tags and title.

Comment: I voted to close because this is a really confusing question - it asks about demo code generated by a tool that doesn't understand what it does, referencing an unrelated tool.

Comment: Instead of looking at ChatGPT demos read the docs and manuals. In this case, [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations).   You have to know even more if you want to use ChatGPT-generated code, to spot and avoid the bugs.

Comment: Imagine two users loading the same customer record to make changes to different properties. The first one saves the changes. When the second one tries to do the same, EF detects this and throws a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. What you do depends on the *business* requirements. You can overwrite the other guy's changes. You can discard your own. You can load the new data and try to merge them, if eg they were on different fields. Or you can ask the user what to do

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#resolving-concurrency-conflicts this example is useful, thanks

Comment: This shows the same options I mentioned, it doesn't tell you which one to use. Only you or rather, your business stakeholders know this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you! This helped me too https://github.com/petercwq/EFCorePractice/blob/master/EFCorePractice/DbContextConcurrencyExtension.cs

Comment: Just to chip in because the question is very different from what's shown in the video. ChatGPT didn't ignore the error like you did here. Just added a movie exists check to see if the item was deleted and if it wasn't it just threw the exception, which is perfectly fine. What you are doing here, by ignoring the exception completely, isn't. [Actual timestamp of code](https://youtu.be/N4sDzidCudQ?t=194)